# How to display 3 rows of text inside one navbar <li>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navbar I want to achieve looks something like this.

```
+--------------------------------------------+
+ navbar-brand img |      |       |  Link 1  |
+ navbar-brand img | Home | About |  Link 2  |
+ navbar-brand img |      |       |  Link 3  |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Also the Home and About links are a bit bigger than the three links on the right. For now I added line-heights and heights to `.navbar-nav li a` to increase the navbar height.

This is the current HTML: **[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/gkUjQX2Pwd)**

```
<div id="header" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg"/>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle toggleButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your CSS code so far.

Comment: @roNn23 Here's the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/gkUjQX2Pwd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the links occupy the whole width with a `display:block`, and add `vertical-align:middle` so all the elements are centered vertically:

```
.navbar-nav  {
    display:inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
    display:block;
}
```

You can see a demo working on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LyLv2wqr/